# Trying to find out why log lineair is slower

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I'm doing a course on algorithms in Python. I'm struggling a bit with Big-O notation. The problem was creating a linear function to find the k-smallest number, and improvind the function to be log linear. I've produced this:

```
import random
import timeit

def linear_find_smallest(values):
    smallest = len(values)
    for i in values:
        if smallest > i != 0:
            smallest = i
    return smallest


def loglinear_find_smallest(values):
    values.sort()
    smallest = len(values)
    for i in values:
        if smallest > i != 0:
            smallest = i
            del values[values.index(i):]
    return smallest


if __name__ == '__main__':
    values = random.sample([i for i in range(1, 10000)], len(range(1, 10000)))
    t = timeit.Timer("linear_find_smallest(%s)" % str(values),
                     setup="from __main__ import linear_find_smallest")
    print("Lineair: found in %f seconds" % t.timeit(number=1000))
    t = timeit.Timer("loglinear_find_smallest(%s)" % str(values),
                     setup="from __main__ import loglinear_find_smallest")
    print("Log linear: found in %f seconds" % t.timeit(number=1000))
```

However, the linear function runs in 1.614513 seconds, and the (I supposed) log linear function in 8.463193 seconds. Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, after you sort, you can just return the first value, which is the smallest by definition of sort.

```
def loglinear_find_smallest(values):
  values.sort()
  return values[0]
```

Now for the real question on complexity. If you are given an arbitrary list, then linear search (`O(n)`) is the best you can do to find the smallest. This is because no matter what your search strategy is, someone can craft an input to your function such that the the first `n-1` places you check for the smallest value is not the smallest value.

With that said, nothing can be faster than a linear search. In particular, log linear (`O(n log n)`) is actually *guaranteed* to be slower since you are doing more operations. I'm really not sure how/why you got confused on log linear ostensibly being faster than linear. Maybe you confused it with logarthmic (`O(log n)`)?

Comment: I'm following a course at http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/analysis.html#programming-exercises. The last question there asked if I could improve the algorithm making it log linear. It had me confused, but actually your answer clears it up.

Comment: @Praetore Ah. I would note that it seems the exercise you linked is to solve a slightly more general problem ([selection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)) than what you have solved. Also, it turns out that in practice, algorithms with worse theoretical complexity can outperform more (theoretically) optimal algorithms, such as [odd-even merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort) in practice outperforms regular merge sort even though even-odd version is `O(n log^2 n)` vs theoretically optimal `O(n log n)` for sorting in general.

Comment: Okay tnx! When I'll get to the part of the course on sorting algorithms, I'll test it out.